# Problem in TimeZone display in java while using Russian locale

Tags: java, timezone

I am facing a problem while using Russian locale, Time Zone part of the date is not converting to Russian.
i.e. if "Aug 10, 2010 4:02:09 PM Yakutsk Time" is the time,
it is converting to -
With Russian locale - "10.08.2010 16:02:09 Yakutsk Time 10" 
With French Locale  -  "août 2010 16:02:09 Heure du Iakoutsk"

I am using following code (Russian locale is supported on my server)

```
     SimpleDateFormat formatterWithoutTimezone = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    SimpleDateFormat formatterServerTimezone = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
    TimeZone serverTimezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    formatterServerTimezone.setTimeZone(serverTimezone);
    String dateSrcStr = formatterWithoutTimezone.format(dateSrc) + " UTC";
    Date dateServerTimezone = formatterServerTimezone.parse(dateSrcStr);
    DateFormat displayFormatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance( DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
    String formatedDate = displayFormatter.format(dateServerTimezone) + " "
    + serverTimezone.getDisplayName(locale);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Zone names are obtained by Java from the sun.util.resources.TimeZoneNamesBundle. There is a TimeZoneNames base resource class and there are localizations (see in rt.jar):

```
TimeZoneNames_de.class  
TimeZoneNames_en.class   
TimeZoneNames_en_CA.class  
TimeZoneNames_en_GB.class  
TimeZoneNames_en_IE.class  
TimeZoneNames_es.class  
TimeZoneNames_fr.class  
TimeZoneNames_it.class  
TimeZoneNames_sv.class
```

So only the above languages have the localized Time Zone names. The following test confirms that most of the locales do not have localized time zone names:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Yakutsk");
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    System.out.println(locale.getDisplayName() + timeZone.getDisplayName(locale));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has it's own built in timezones definitions.  Assuming your timezone is aok on your server, then perhaps the problem lies in the Java definitions.  Lookup [tzupdater](http://java.sun.com/javase/tzupdater_README.html) to see if you need to either find a newer version of the timezones, or build your own.  If you are using an old JVM, try grabbing the latest version to see if your timezone is supported.

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6, This problem is with Russian locale only for all timezones.

For French, German etc Time Zone String converted to corresponding language.